# Custom Post Type Author Array Problem

Tags: custom-post-types, author, array

I am trying to create an author.php page that calls custom post types by the author appearing on that page. My problem is that when using the code below -- which filters for the post type 'video' -- the code outputs all custom post types, not just 'video'. The caveat is when I remove the array's author key and variable `'author' => $author` which then has the effect of allowing the code to output the desired custom post type 'video' but from every author. Any ideas of how to fix this?

**Code used:**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'audio' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'author'         => $author
    );


    $author_videos = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : while ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : $author_videos->the_post(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>       
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$author`? Also: you have `'post_type' => array( 'audio' )`, rather than `video`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the codex page [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)? There it states:

> when a viewer clicks on a link to a post author, by default he or she is taken to a page listing the posts from that particular author in chronological order

This depends on having the correct links setup, which can be done with [`the_author_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_posts_link) or [`wp_list_authors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors). A custom query shouldn't be necessary, you can alter the post types by hooking into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

**Code:**

```
function wpse124293_cpts_for_author_archives( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() )
        return;
    if ( is_author() ) {
        //only show cpt audio
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'audio' ) );
        //to show builtin post and cpt audio use: array( 'post', 'audio' )
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse124293_cpts_for_author_archives' );
```